# 'Session has not been configured for this application or request.' in .NET Core 6 WEB API

Tags: .net, session, exception, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to make web app with .net core 6 and react but there is a problem when I try to use api which is authorized for specific role.

That's my code:

```
public class SessionBasedAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<SessionBasedAuthorizationRequirement>
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        public SessionBasedAuthorizationHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, SessionBasedAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
        {
            string role = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Role");
            if (role is null)
            {
                context.Fail();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            if (role == requirement.Role.ToString())
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            else
            {
                context.Fail();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I try to use something with specific role it give me exception on this line:

```
string role = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Role");
```

With exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Session has not been configured for this application or request.'
```

Can you give me an advice how to fix it ?

Comment: Have you tried to add `app.UseSession(); ` before `app.UseMvc();`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem in "program.cs" by taking the line of

```
"app.UseSession();"
```

over the part of

```
"app.MapControllerRoute()" and "app.UseEndpoints()"
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do mean "by replacing" instead of "by taking"?

Comment: yes i mean replace the line over the  "app.MapControllerRoute()" and "app.UseEndpoints()"